# Operators in an interpreter

Tags: operators, interpreter

I'm making an interpreter just for fun. First I'm trying to evaluate expressions. The evaluation returns a Value object and every type has  it's own Value structure. So for example:

```
struct Value  // This is the abstract base class for every value type
{
     int type;
};

struct IntegerValue : public Value
{
     int value;

     IntegerValue(int value) : value(value), type(VALUE_INTEGER) {}
};
```

I don't know if this is a nice design (probably not) but works so far. But as I define new types and operatos, the evaluation methods get huge. For example at operator '==' the left side and right side can be string, integer, float and so on... So I guess I need to define operators for Value structures and not check them in the eval methods (and maybe even allow user-defined operators like in c++) but I just can't think of a fast, elegant and easily extendable design. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my postscript interpreter (written in C), I defined my typed-objects as a union so I could carefully arrange the members to overlay the same memory.

```
union {
    word tag;
    struct { word tag; word pad0; int val; } _int;
    struct { word tag; word pad0; float val; } _real;
    //...
} object;
```

You may not need to be so memory-conscious in your project, but I've gotten a lot of mileage from this structure.

---

As for handling the explosion of type-combinations that can occur. I've recently implemented several numeric types in my APL interpreter and with the help of macros (which hide a lot more code), the 3 possible types become 9 separate cases:

```
/* apply binary math op to nums, yielding num
TODO: additional numeric types.
    configurable overflow promotion handling.
 */
#define BIN_MATH_FUNC(func,z,x,y,overflow,domainI,domainD) \
     switch(NUMERIC_TYPES(x,y)){ \
     case TYPEPAIR(IMM,IMM): DOM(domainI,z,numimm(x),numimm(y)) \
                             if (overflow(numimm(x),numimm(y))) \
                                 z=flo((D)numimm(x) func (D)numimm(y)); \
                             else z=num(numimm(x) func numimm(y)); break; \
     case TYPEPAIR(IMM,FIX): DOM(domainI,z,numimm(x),numint(y)) \
                             if (overflow(numimm(x),numint(y))) \
                                 z=flo((D)numimm(x) func (D)numint(y)); \
                             else z=num(numimm(x) func numint(y)); break; \
     case TYPEPAIR(IMM,FLO): DOM(domainD,z,numimm(x),numdbl(y)) \
                             z=flo(numimm(x) func numdbl(y)); break; \
     case TYPEPAIR(FIX,IMM): DOM(domainI,z,numint(x),numimm(y)) \
                             if (overflow(numint(x),numimm(y))) \
                                 z=flo((D)numint(x) func (D)numimm(y)); \
                             else z=num(numint(x) func numimm(y)); break; \
     case TYPEPAIR(FIX,FIX): DOM(domainI,z,numint(x),numint(y)) \
                             if (overflow(numint(x),numint(y))) \
                                 z=flo((D)numint(x) func (D)numint(y)); \
                             else z=num(numint(x) func numint(y)); break; \
     case TYPEPAIR(FIX,FLO): DOM(domainD,z,numint(x),numdbl(y)) \
                             z=flo(numint(x) func numdbl(y)); break; \
     case TYPEPAIR(FLO,IMM): DOM(domainD,z,numdbl(x),numimm(y)) \
                             z=flo(numdbl(x) func numimm(y)); break; \
     case TYPEPAIR(FLO,FIX): DOM(domainD,z,numdbl(x),numint(y)) \
                             z=flo(numdbl(x) func numint(y)); break; \
     case TYPEPAIR(FLO,FLO): DOM(domainD,z,numdbl(x),numdbl(y)) \
                             z=flo(numdbl(x) func numdbl(y)); break; \
     }
```

The `func` argument to the macro is a C math operator like `+` or `*` or `%`. So I just need to present floating point number where I want floating-point math or integers where I want integer math. The `domain?` functions are only needed for detecting division by zero.

The `TYPEPAIR` helper macro is very useful, and perhaps not obvious how it should work. The arguments are `enum` values, C's version of atomic symbols which are represented as small integers. So here I just needed to distinguish 3 numeric types, so I make an `enum` for them.

```
enum { IMM = 1, FIX, FLO, NTYPES };
```

Normally `enum` values are allocated starting with 0, but for the math trick, I want these to start with 1. Then I can treat these values like a *number system* with `NTYPES` as the radix or base. With the symbols defined like this, I can calculate a 2-*digit* type as a single numeric value. This is a constant value, so if it's calculated by a macro, it can be used as a switch case.

```
#define TYPEPAIR(a,b)  ((a)*NTYPES+(b))
```

It also be composed to produce a larger type-pattern number representation.

```
TYPEPAIR(TYPEPAIR(IMM,FIX),FLO)
```

which expands to

```
((((IMM)*NTYPES+(FIX)))*NTYPES+(FLO))
```

This kind of stuff lets me do matching of larger patterns of things with less code. Instead of something like

```
if (TYPE(x)==IMM && TYPE(y)==FIX) //...
//...
```

which isn't expressible as a `switch`.

Comment: As for my other question, a really nice answer! Thank you!